# Deleting a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Below I am creating a linked list and then trying to delete it, however the program will compile and run, but the linked list will not delete for me and the program gets stuck in a loop or something (basically it does not terminate when it should I have to kill it manually)

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong, prior to writing the 'deletePoly' function everything was fine (i.e. program would compile and run) to be going ok but I have gone through the cod a 100 times and I can't seem to see what the issue is.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE (15)

typedef struct link {
    double coeff;
    int pow;
    struct link * next;
} poly;

poly *polyArray[MEMORY_SIZE];// array of 15 polynomials to play with

// /** The function prototypes */
void createPoly(poly **);                   
void showPoly(poly *);                      
void deletePoly(poly *);                    


int main(void) {


  int a;

  for( a = 0; a < MEMORY_SIZE; a++ )
    {
      polyArray[a] = NULL;//Initialise each element of the array of pointers to NULL
    }//end for

        createPoly(&polyArray[0]);
        showPoly(polyArray[0]);

        srand(time(NULL));
        createPoly(&polyArray[1]);
        showPoly(polyArray[1]);

        showPoly(polyArray[0]); 

        int count;
        for(count = 0; count < MEMORY_SIZE; count++)
        {
          deletePoly(polyArray[count]);
        }   

          showPoly(polyArray[0]);   

          return 0;

}// End Main Function



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


void createPoly(poly **node) {

    poly *tempnode; //To hold the temporary last address
    tempnode = (poly*)malloc( sizeof(poly) ); //create the first node
    *node = tempnode; //Store the head address to the reference variable

    int flag = 1 + rand()%3;; // A flag to control the number of terms
    int counter;

    for( counter = 0; counter <= flag; counter++ )
    {
          tempnode->pow = ( flag-counter );
      tempnode->coeff = ( (double)(rand()%20) )/( (double)(1 + rand()%20) );

      if( (counter < flag) && (counter >= 0)  )
        {
           tempnode->next = (poly*)malloc( sizeof(poly) ); //Grow the list
        }
      else if ( counter == flag )
        {
          tempnode->next = NULL;
        }

      tempnode = tempnode->next;
    }

}//end function createPoly

void deletePoly(poly *node) {

  poly *temp;//Create pointer to poly called 'temp'

  while( node->next != NULL );
  {
    temp = node->next;//Assign the address of the next node to 'temp'
    free( node );//Delete the current node
    node = temp;//Assign the address of the next node in the list to 'node'
  }//end while

  node = NULL;//Set pointer 'node' to NULL to prevent a "lingering" pointer

}//end function 'deletePoly'


void showPoly(poly * node) {

    while(node->next != NULL) {

    if(node->coeff == 0)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }
    else if(node->coeff == 1 && node->pow > 1)
    {
      printf("[x^%i]", node->pow);
      node = node->next;
    }
    else if(node->coeff == 1 && node->pow == 1)
    {
      printf("[x]");
      node = node->next;
    }   
    else if(node->coeff != 0 && node->pow == 0)
    {
      printf("(%.2lf)", node->coeff);
      node = node->next;
    }   
    else if(node->pow == 0 && node->coeff == 0)
    {
      node = node->next;
    }   
    else if(node->coeff != 1 && node->pow > 1 && node->coeff != 0)
    {
      printf("(%.2lf)[x^%i]", node->coeff, node->pow);
      node = node->next;
    }
    else if(node->coeff != 1 && node->pow == 1 && node->coeff != 0)
    {
      printf("(%.2lf)[x]", node->coeff);// no need to print x to the power 0
      node = node->next;
    }

    if(node->next != NULL)
    {
      printf(" + ");
    }
    }
}//end function showPoly
```

Comment: `while( node->next != NULL );` --> `while( node != NULL )` and `node=NULL` is no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete code should be:

```
void deletePoly(poly* node)
{
   poly* next;

   while (node != NULL) 
   {
       next = node->next;
       free(node);
       node = next;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would I have to write struct node, when I used a typedef to change the name of that type to poly?

Comment: @user4225083 Yes once you have typecasted you can use poly. I was just being generic here

Comment: Ok, thanks. You have ( node != NULL ) Why is this? My understanding of my way would be that I am accessing the member of each node called next and seeing if it points to another node or not, obviously this does not work. My understanding of your way is that in the first line of the while body, you are assigning the address of the next node to the pointer variable next and then freeing the current node and assigning the pointer to the next node (i.e. next)  to the now lingering pointer variable 'node' and of course if this value is null the while loop will end. Is this correct?

Comment: @user4225083 Yes your interpretation of this logic is right. Thank me by accepting this as answer if it had answered your question

Comment: You are fixing the problem in `deletePoly`, but you forgot to say that after deleting the array, the following line in main ( `showPoly(polyArray[0])`) accesses a freed memory bloc.